# Navigating between activities is not happening

Tags: android

I am trying to navigate between two activities but the application crashes and requests for a force close.

Here is my code:
1st Activity

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//public boolean returnFlag = false;
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button YesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    YesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Activity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
          }
    });


}
```

2nd Activity:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.answerspage);


    Button butTryAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_tryagain);
    butTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HelloWorldActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

}
```

main.xml - of HelloWorldActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"             

android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:textAppearance="?

android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1"         `android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="27dp" android:text="Welcome"></TextView>`
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="Is your question ready??" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="29dp"></TextView>`
<Button android:text="Yes" android:layout_width="wrap_content" `android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"></Button>`
<Button android:text="No"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" `android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginRight="38dp" android:layout_marginTop="54dp"></Button>`
</RelativeLayout>
```

answerspage.xml - xml file of Activity2

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1" `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Try again" android:id="@+id/button1" `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/id_tryagain" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"` `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"></Button>`


       <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Quit" `android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id_quit" android:layout_marginLeft="29dp" android:layout_marginTop="127dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>`
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" `android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="46dp" android:editable="true"></TextView>`
     </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.HelloWorld"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>


I have gone through http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/ to implement the same
```

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace for the crash? If you are using Eclipse, switch to viewing LogCat and look for stack trace that was spewed out upon crashing. If you can't make sense of the stack trace, then post it here for us to see.

Comment: i am getting NullPointerException and the Stack trace says
Exception processing async thread queue
Exception processing async thread queue
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIObjectValue cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.IJavaArray

Comment: If the two answers below don't hold your solution (they are right about obtaining the context from HelloWorldActivity.this, by the way), the post as much of the stack trace as you can get from LogCat. The source of the NullPointerException is likely buried somewhere in your stack trace.

Comment: The below mentioned solutions didnt help. I am posting my error msges which i got in the logcat. Pls Check.
ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
ERROR/BatteryService(67): usbOnlinePath not found
ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryVoltagePath not found
ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryTemperaturePath not found
ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(67): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter

Comment: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
ERROR/System(67): Failure starting core service
ERROR/System(67): java.lang.SecurityException
ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
ERROR/System(67):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg

Comment: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
ERROR/logwrapper(148): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
ERROR/logwrapper(150): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
ERROR/logwrapper(151): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory

Comment: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(67): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
And i can see **Source not found** error message and a button to **Edit Source Look Up Path** from ActivityThread.perforLauchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord,Intent)line:2663

Comment: Sorry but this isn't the crash reason, you probably didn't get the good part of the log. Launch the app, clear the log (with the cross button), and make the app crash. Then, edit you question and a the logcat. Because commenting log isn't very eye friendly.

Comment: I'm with NitroG42 on this one. Get a fresh stack trace - assuming LogCat is set up the same on your system, the stack trace from the crash should be in red. If it doesn't contain the word NullPointerException, then you're grabbing the wrong stuff. LogCat receives a lot of output, so you'll need to filter out the unrelated stuff. Once you've got the stack trace, edit your question and append the stack trace.

Comment: In LogCat Viewer Post the stack trace related to your files , i mean it would show somewhere that error in helloworld.<ext> line <#> that would be usefull to debug

Answer (score 3):

In onClick method, you shouldn't use view.getContext() to start the intent.
Instead, use :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this,Activity2.class);
```

for HelloWorldActivity and

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity2.this, HelloWorldActivity.class);
```

for Activity2

Answer (score 1):

The context you're using is wrong.

try doing this

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Context context = null;

//public boolean returnFlag = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set the context here
    context = getApplicationContext();

    Button YesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    YesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context ,Activity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });


}
```

Hope this helps.